# Equality of ideals in $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I am required to prove that in the ring $R=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-7}]$ (where $8=2^3=(1+\sqrt{-7})(1-\sqrt{-7})$)
$$\sqrt{I}=\langle2,1+\sqrt{-7}\rangle$$
where $I=8R$

I am really struggling with this, can someone give me a hint?

edit: I have managed to prove that $\sqrt{I}\supseteq\langle2,1+\sqrt{-7}\rangle$
since $2^3,(1+\sqrt{-7})^4\in I$

Comment: Simply compute the square of $\langle 2, 1 + \sqrt{-7}\rangle$. But it doesn't look like the answer is $8R$.

Comment: @WhatsUp $\sqrt{I}$ usually denotes the radical of the ideal, not its square root.

Comment: @Wojowu Your'e right, that was my intention

Comment: @Wojowu Aha... Sorry then ^^||

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $J = (2, 1 + \sqrt {-7})$. Obviously, $2 ∈ \sqrt I$. So let’s investigate modulo $2$:

Let $S = R/2R$. For $x ∈ R$, since $2R ⊆ \sqrt I $,
$$x ∈ \sqrt I \iff [x]_{2R} ∈ \sqrt I/2R.$$
However, $\operatorname{char} S = 2$ – so $[(1 \pm \sqrt {-7}))^2]_{2R} = [8]_{2R} = 0$, so $1 \pm \sqrt{-7} ∈ \sqrt I$. Therefore $J ⊆ \sqrt I$.

But $R/J \cong ℤ/2ℤ$, so $J$ is maximal, so $J = \sqrt I$.

Comment: (In case anyone noticed all the edits: Sorry about them – lack of sleep. I kept noticing mistakes, but couldn’t correct them properly. I think it’s correct now, will go to sleep. Please leave a comment if I still got something wrong …)